# Check row if value exists

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-apps, google-sheets-api

```
if (purchaseSheet && range.getColumn() == purchasedColumn && ["Yes", "No", "Repeat"].indexOf(range.getValue()) > -1) {
    if (targetSheet.getRange("A:A").getValue() != taskID) {
        sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange); //- moveTo
    }
}
```

My second if statement doesn't seem to check the range to see if a row contains the same taskID.

How do I check "Column A" to see if a value exists or not in a row?

Comment: Do you want to check if taskID exists anywhere in column A or do you want to go through every row and copy the value to the row where taskID does/does not exist?

Comment: use getValues for a range.

Comment: The code is not complete. Reference: [mcve].

Comment: @RobinGertenbach - I simple want to see if the taskID exists anywhere in Column A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you get a range that is more than a cell and call `getValue()` on it it will only get one value, the one in the top left cell of the range.

What you want to do is

```
targetSheet
    .getRange("A:A")
    .getValues()
    .map(function(row) {return row[0];})
    .indexOf(taskID) > -1
```

if you want it to be found or `=== -1` if you want it not to exist

Comment: How would I then get the range of the row it's found on?

Comment: just remove the comparison to -1 and you'll get the 0 based index of the row of the range